# Is $x^8 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$ an irreducible polynomial or not in GF $2^8$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is $x^8 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$ an irreducible polynomial or not in Galois Field $2^8$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exponents are [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Perhaps that might have some relevance.

Comment: If you shift $x\mapsto x+1$, you have a more symmetric $x^8+x^5+x^4+x^3+1$.

Comment: Couldn't you just try using long division and see what happens when you divide by polynomials of degree 4 or less?  There are only 8 possibilities, since you can be sure the constant coefficient is 1.  And surely it can't take that long to go through them all, can it?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The field is $\mathbb{F}_{2^8}$, which has a lot more nonzero possibilites for coefficients than just $1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Oops.  Sorry.

Comment: May I ask, is this homework?  Research?  Contest Math?  Trying to hack the NSA?  Terrorist demands involving Galois Fields?

Comment: I believe StephenMontgomery-Smith is on the right track.  If you can rule out the factors $\pmod 2$ then that would establish that it is irreducible $\pmod {256}$, since $a \equiv b \pmod{256} \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod {2}$.  However, you find a solution $\mod{2}$ it doesn't imply that there is one $\mod{256}$, but you can use this approach to rule out any possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear. If you are truly asking whether this polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^8+x^5+x^3+x^2+1
$$ is irreducible in the ring $GF(256)[x]$, then the answer is trivially **NO!** This is because:

- Either it is reducible over $GF(2)$ in which case it is reducible over the extension field also,
- Or it is irreducible over $GF(2)$ in which case $GF(2)[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field of 256 elements, and thus isomorphic (or equal to) $GF(256)$. In this case $p(x)$ has 8 distinct zeros in the field, namely the cosets $x^{2^i}+\langle p(x)\rangle$, $i=0,1,2,\ldots,7$. Consequently $p(x)$ would split into linear factors over $GF(256)$.

But this was a bit naughty of me, because I took your phrasing of the question literally. Presumably you would not ask things like: "Is $x^2+1$ irreducible over the complex numbers?", because you know that it factors as $(x+i)(x-i)$ in $\Bbb{C}[x]$. The only sensible guess is that you are inquiring whether $p(x)$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$.

As pointed out in the comments you need to show that $p(x)$ has no factors of degree 4 or lower. The usual suspects are $x,x+1,x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1,x^3+x^2+1,x^4+x+1,x^4+x^3+1$ and
$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. If you were given this as an exercise, your teacher/book must have produced this at some earlier point (otherwise it would a bit naughty of them - barring introduction of a general algorithm like Berlekamp's).

- Because $p(x)$ has five terms including $1$ we can immediately rule out the linear factors.
- The quadratic factor is a factor of $x^3+1$. But $x^8+x^5=(x^3+1)x^5$, so 
  $$p(x)\equiv x^2\pmod{x^2+x+1}.$$ Thus no irreducible quadratic factor.
- Both the cubic irreducible polynomials are factors of $x^7+1$ (the multiplicative group of the field $GF(8)$ is cyclic of order seven). We see that $x^8\equiv x\pmod{x^7+1}$, so $p(x)\equiv x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1\pmod {x^7+1}$. If this were divisible by $x^3+x+1$ then so would $x^5+x^2=x^2(x^3+1)=x^2(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ which is absurd. Likewise, if it were divisible by $x^3+x^2+1$, then so would $x^5+x=x(x^4+1)=x(x+1)^4$ again violating uniqueness of factorization.

This leaves the possibility that $p(x)$ could be a product of two irreducible quartics, i.e. a product of two of $f_1(x)=x^4+x+1$, $f_2(x)=x^4+x^3+1$, $f_3(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.
Could $f_1(x)$ be a factor? We have $f_1(x)^2=x^8+x^2+1$, so
$$
p(x)\equiv x^5+x^3\pmod{f_1(x)}.
$$
As in the cubic case this leads to a contradiction as $x^5+x^3=x^3(x+1)^2$ is not divisible by $f_1(x)$.

Because $p(x)$ contains odd degree terms, it is not a square of a polynomial. The only remaining possibility is
$$
p(x)=f_2(x)f_3(x).
$$
Leaving it to you to rule out this possibility. Either by brute force or by using one of the techniques outlined here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say at the beginning that I'm not very familiar with this area, I just thought I'd take a shot at this since there hasn't been much.  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Suppose you have the polynomials

$$ P_0(x) = x^8 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$$

$$ P_1(x) = A_7\,x^7 + A_6\,x^6 + A_5\,x^5 + A_4\,x^4 + A_3\,x^3 + A_2\,x^2 + A_1\,x^1 + A_0\,x^0 $$
$$ P_2(x) = B_7\,x^7 + B_6\,x^6 + B_5\,x^5 + B_4\,x^4 + B_3\,x^3 + B_2\,x^2 + B_1\,x^1 + B^0\,x^0 $$

Now, if $P_0(x) \equiv P_1(x)\cdot P_2(x) \pmod{256}$, then $P_0(x) \equiv P_1(x)\cdot P_2(x) \pmod{2}$ since $2 \mid 256$.  So we can check:

$$\begin{align}
0 & \equiv A_7\,B_7\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_6\,B_7 + A_7\,B_6\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_5\,B_7 + A_6\,B_6 + A_7\,B_5\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_4\,B_7 + A_5\,B_6 + A_6\,B_5 + A_7\,B_4\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_3\,B_7 + A_4\,B_6 + A_5\,B_5 + A_6\,B_4 + A_7\,B_3\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_2\,B_7 + A_3\,B_6 + A_4\,B_5 + A_5\,B_4 + A_6\,B_3 + A_7\,B_2\pmod{2} \\
1 & \equiv A_1\,B_7 + A_2\,B_6 + A_3\,B_5 + A_4\,B_4 + A_5\,B_3 + A_6\,B_2 + A_7\,B_1\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_0\,B_7 + A_1\,B_6 + A_2\,B_5 + A_3\,B_4 + A_4\,B_3 + A_5\,B_2 + A_6\,B_1 + A_7\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_0\,B_6 + A_1\,B_5 + A_2\,B_4 + A_3\,B_3 + A_4\,B_2 + A_5\,B_1 + A_6\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
1 & \equiv A_0\,B_5 + A_1\,B_4 + A_2\,B_3 + A_3\,B_2 + A_4\,B_1 + A_5\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_0\,B_4 + A_1\,B_3 + A_2\,B_2 + A_3\,B_1 + A_4\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
1 & \equiv A_0\,B_3 + A_1\,B_2 + A_2\,B_1 + A_3\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
1 & \equiv A_0\,B_2 + A_1\,B_1 + A_2\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
0 & \equiv A_0\,B_1 + A_1\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
1 & \equiv A_0\,B_0\pmod{2} \\
\end{align}$$

This is fairly simple to check with a computer, my search turned up that it is irreducible.

Comment: Do you know that "equality in $GF(256)$" does not mean "congruent modulo $256$"? The polynomial factors over $GF(256)$. What you probably can show this way is that it does not factor modulo $2$.

Comment: I took it to mean that the coefficients are equal modulo 256, is that mistaken?

Comment: It is mistaken. But as i tried to explain in my answer, the only sensible question here is the one that you have worked on - treating the unknown coefficients as integers modulo two.

Comment: I'm using this as a reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html and it seems to suggest (although admittedly, not outright say) that a polynomial is irreducible iff it cannot be factored when the coefficients are treated as field objects.  What alternative definition are you suggesting?

Comment: The OP left it unclear what the "field objects" are? If they are integers modulo two, then your solution is fine. If they are elements of $GF(256)$, then one of the equivalent definitions of $GF(256)$ is the quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^8+x^5+x^3+x^2+1\rangle$. If $\alpha$ is the coset of $x$ in that ring, then $x-\alpha$ is a divisor of this polynomial. Observe that $\alpha\in GF(256)$, so the coefficients of that factor are "field objects". This is what the OP, taken literally, asked. However, it is my "expert" opinion that the OP really wanted to ask the question that you answered.